# Active or Inactive columns in a GridView, based on another column in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have some columns active or inactive based on the value for the check-box from the first column "Checked" as it can be seen from below picture. If the check-box is not checked, than the two columns [2] and [3] should have all the rows inactive. But if the user checks the check-box than the two columns [2] and [3] should be set to active in order for the user to have the possibility to enter a date type data for each column (eg. 01/01/2014, etc).

[image: example]

I created a DataTable dtCountries, which I used it as the datasource for my datagridview, but I don't know how to make the above described feature?
Could you please give me any hints?

My code looks like this:

```
DataTable dtCountries = new DataTable();
dtCountries.Columns.Add("Checked", typeof(bool));
dtCountries.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
dtCountries.Columns.Add("ParamDecKey1", typeof(string));
dtCountries.Columns.Add("ParamDecKey2", typeof(string));

dtCountries.Rows.Add(false, "Country_1", "", "");
dtCountries.Rows.Add(false, "Country_2", "", "");
...
dtCountries.Rows.Add(false, "Country_Nth", "", "");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCountries;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
```

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [CellValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  event. Check if this cell is cell with checkbox, if yes, get from the row columns 2-3 and enable/disable it.